# Unexpected value 'MatTableDataSource' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular

I am developing an angular application using angular 5. I wanted to use "MatTableDataSource" from angular- material. But i am getting this error

Unexpected value 'MatTableDataSource' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

I search for a solution for this problem. I found this solution in git

"https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10981"

There a user named @dliebel gave a solution. I applied it but getting this error again and again. app.module.ts is specified below

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SellDetailFormComponent } from './sellDetail/sellDetailForm.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HotTableModule } from '@handsontable/angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatTableModule, MatSortModule,MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { SellTableComponent } from './sellDetail/sellTable.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'sellTable', component: SellTableComponent }


];

@NgModule({
declarations: [
  AppComponent,SellTableComponent
 ],
imports: [
BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), ReactiveFormsModule,HotTableModule.forRoot() ,
 HttpClientModule, HotTableModule, 
CommonModule,MatTableModule,MatSortModule,MatTableDataSource
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Share your app.module

Comment: @Vikas i edited my question

Comment: `MatDataTableSource` is not an angular module, remove it from the imports

Comment: I guess the issue is fixed now?

Comment: yes.thank you very much.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Please add it as an answer so this question can be marked as answered by the OP.

Comment: I want to know how this issue is fixed.. I removed it from imports, but got an error.
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

Answer (score 4):

You should not import it in app module , just import and use it directly in the component.ts file

and if that doesn't solve the issue

It may be version compatibility issue like i had 
Most likely i needed to update "@angular/material" and "@angular/cdk" to "5.0.0-rc.2"  and this solved my problem

just see what version is compatible with your need and use

Answer (score 2):

Try to import module correctly.

```
import { MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatTableModule, MatSortModule } from '@angular/material';

imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule, 
    MatInputModule, 
    MatPaginatorModule, 
    MatTableModule, 
    MatSortModule 
  ]
```

worked fine for me.

Comment: Format your answer a bit

Answer (score 2):

`MatDataTableSource` is not an angular module. Remove it from the imports. You just add your component itself, following **angular material**.

```
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
```

Answer (score 1):

The new import for `MatTableDataSource` since the update is now

`import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';`

Answer (score 0):

I removed "MatTableDataSource" form the imports and now it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

After importing it in the module, it worked for me